# Dynamic Programming [Longest Palindromic Substring]

Tags: java, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I solved this problem using recursion and memoization but struggled to come up with an iterative solution. Can someone help me to convert the below recursive solution into iterative solution with step-by-step explanation ??? Thanks in advance.

```
class Solution {
    Boolean[][] memo;
    public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        memo = new Boolean[n][n];

        return helper(s);
    }

    public boolean isPal(String s,int st,int en) {
        if (st >= en) {
            return true;
        }

        if (memo[st][en] != null) {
            return memo[st][en];
        }

        if (s.charAt(st) == s.charAt(en) && isPal(s,st + 1,en - 1)) {
            memo[st][en] = true;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String helper(String s) {
        
        int st = -1;
        int maxLen = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i<s.length();i++) {
       //     st = i;
            for (int j = i;j<s.length();j++) {
                if (isPal(s,i,j) && (j - i + 1) > maxLen) {
                    st = i; 
                    maxLen = j - i + 1;
                }
            }
        
        }

        if (st == -1) {
            return "";
        }

        return s.substring(st,st + maxLen);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find solutions for the particular problem on [leetcode](leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/editorial).

Comment: You should also show your recursive solution.  Then we can offer suggestions in making it iterative.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.